# android : Xfermode masking disappearing on 180 degree rotation of Canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas, drawable, xfermode

I am inspired by the the new Material Design animations and I worked to create a similar drawable that is used in new support v7 Action Bar Drawer Toggle.

I created a CustomDrawable. All I actually did is that I created a Play triangle on canvas and pause logo on the left of the left margin of the visible canvas. I rotate the canvas according to the progress and restore it. Then I used Xfermode to crop the rotated result into a circle.

I cant find the solution to the problem.

The problem is that the xFermode is not applied to the 180 degree rotated result(after calling canvas.restore()).

Here is the code of Activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

ImageView iv;
CustomDrawable drawable = new CustomDrawable();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button);
    iv.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    iv.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);

    iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            float[] values = { 0, 1 };
            if (drawable.getProgress() != 0) {
                values[0] = drawable.getProgress();
                values[1] = 0;
            }
            ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(drawable,
                    "progress", values);
            animator.setDuration(2000);
            animator.start();

        }
    });
 }
}
```

And the code for the CustomDrawable

```
public class CustomDrawable extends Drawable {
    private float mProgress = 0;
    private Paint mPaint = new Paint();
    private Path mPath = new Path();
    private final float rootTwo = (float) Math.sqrt(2);
    private final float rootThree = (float) Math.sqrt(3);
    private float radius = 0;
    private float side = 0;
    private Point[] triangle = new Point[3];
    Paint xferpaint = new Paint();
    Canvas cropper;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    Interpolator interpolator = new AnticipateOvershootInterpolator();
    private float width;
    Rect rec1, rec2;

public CustomDrawable() {
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    xferpaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    xferpaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    xferpaint.setAntiAlias(true);
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.getClipBounds(bound);
    boundsf.set(bound);
    if (radius == 0) {
        radius = Math.min(bound.centerX(), bound.centerY());
        radius -= 5;

        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bound.width(), bound.height(),
                Config.ARGB_8888);
        cropper = new Canvas(bitmap);
        cropper.drawCircle(bound.centerX(), bound.centerY(), radius,
                xferpaint);

        xferpaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.DST_IN));

        side = rootTwo * radius;

        triangle[0] = new Point(
                (int) (bound.centerX() + (side / rootThree)),
                bound.centerY());
        triangle[1] = new Point(bound.centerX()
                - (int) (side / (2 * rootThree)), bound.centerY()
                - (int) (side / 2));
        triangle[2] = new Point(bound.centerX()
                - (int) (side / (2 * rootThree)), bound.centerY()
                + (int) (side / 2));
        width = side / 4;
        rec1 = new Rect((int) (-bound.centerX() - (3 * width / 2)),
                (int) (bound.centerY() - (side / 2)),
                (int) (-bound.centerX() - (width / 2)),
                (int) (bound.centerY() + (side / 2)));
        rec2 = new Rect((int) (-bound.centerX() + (width / 2)),
                (int) (bound.centerY() - (side / 2)),
                (int) (-bound.centerX() + (3 * width / 2)),
                (int) (bound.centerY() + (side / 2)));
    }

    mPath.rewind();
    mPath.moveTo(triangle[0].x, triangle[0].y);
    mPath.lineTo(triangle[1].x, triangle[1].y);
    mPath.lineTo(triangle[2].x, triangle[2].y);
    mPath.close();
    mPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#378585"));
    canvas.drawPaint(mPaint);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0400"));
    canvas.rotate(180 * interpolator.getInterpolation(mProgress), 0,
            bound.centerY());
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    canvas.drawRect(rec1, mPaint);
    canvas.drawRect(rec2, mPaint);
    canvas.restore();
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, xferpaint);
}

@Override
public int getOpacity() {
    return mPaint.getAlpha();
}

@Override
public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
    mPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
}

@Override
public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter filter) {
    mPaint.setColorFilter(filter);
}

public float getProgress() {
    return mProgress;
}

public void setProgress(float progress) {
    mProgress = progress;
    invalidateSelf();
}

}
```

Comment: canvas.restore() is useless since there is no canvas.save/saveLayer

Comment: It does effect. Without it the canvas will retain its rotated state and the mask will be rotated as well when mask is drawn.

Comment: restore(0 docs: "This call balances a previous call to save(), and is used to remove all modifications to the matrix/clip state since the last save call. **It is an error to call restore() more times than save() was called**.", see the last sentence in **bold**

Comment: It doesn't throw error on restore(). There must have been a call to save before. It removes the mod to matrix and clip since last save but doesnt remove what I draw on canvas.If I doesnt remove the modification I did to the matrix (in this case rotation) then the modification will affect the mask as well. You can use my code as well. I tried removing restore() but it worsened the problem.

Comment: have you seen my answer?

Comment: added `draw` method without using `Canvas.clipPath()`, have you seen it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is your simplified Drawable:

```
class CustomDrawable extends Drawable implements ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener {
    private float mProgress = 0;
    private Paint mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    private Path mPath;
    private Path mClipPath;

    public CustomDrawable() {
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPaint.setColor(0xffFF0400);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBoundsChange(Rect bounds) {
        mClipPath = new Path();
        int cx = bounds.centerX();
        int cy = bounds.centerY();
        int radius = Math.min(cx, cy) - 5;
        mClipPath.addCircle(cx, cy, radius, Path.Direction.CCW);

        final float rootTwo = (float) Math.sqrt(2);
        final float rootThree = (float) Math.sqrt(3);

        float side = rootTwo * radius;
        mPath = new Path();
        mPath.moveTo(cx + (side / rootThree), cy);
        mPath.lineTo(cx - side / (2 * rootThree), cy - side / 2);
        mPath.lineTo(cx - side / (2 * rootThree), cy + side / 2);
        mPath.close();

        float width = side / 4;
        addRect(-cx - (3 * width / 2), cy - (side / 2), width, side);
        addRect(-cx + (width / 2), cy - (side / 2), width, side);
    }

    private void addRect(float l, float t, float dx, float dy) {
        mPath.addRect(l, t, l + dx, t + dy, Path.Direction.CCW);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.clipPath(mClipPath);

        canvas.drawColor(0xff378585);
        Rect bounds = getBounds();
        canvas.rotate(mProgress, 0, bounds.centerY());
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }

    public void switchIcons() {
        float[] values = { 0, 180 };
        if (mProgress != 0) {
            values[0] = mProgress;
            values[1] = 0;
        }
        ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(values).setDuration(2000);
        animator.setInterpolator(new AnticipateOvershootInterpolator());
        animator.addUpdateListener(this);
        animator.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        mProgress = (Float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return mPaint.getAlpha();
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        mPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter filter) {
        mPaint.setColorFilter(filter);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: this is `draw()` method without `Canvas.clipPath` and without creating a "mask" `Bitmap`:

```
    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(0xff378585);

        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(mProgress, 0, cy);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        canvas.restore();

        canvas.saveLayer(null, mDstInPaint, 0);
        canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, radius, mPaint);
        canvas.restore();
    }
```

where: mDstInPaint is a `Paint` object with xfermode set in Drawable's constructor:

```
mDstInPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
```

Comment: My code worked as well. I just required to have Canvas.save() which I didn't. By the way Your code looks more clean. Also I am new to this canvas thing. Thanks a lot buddy.

Comment: so this is what i was saing from the beginning: there is restore() called without matching save() call